# Can't get computed style of position that uses calc() in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

With an element that uses `calc()` for positioning (e.g. `div { left: calc(100% - 50px); }`) Safari returns nil for window.getComputedStyle(elem).left

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe getBoundingClientRect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
var elem = document.querySelector(/* selector */);
var elemPositionLeft = elem.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

Comment: This will only get me the offset from the edge of the screen. In the case that I'm using this (where the element goes past the edge) this is not the correct value.

Comment: @NomNomCameron _"In the case that I'm using this (where the element goes past the edge) this is not the correct value"_ Can you describe expected result?, create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?